# Rotate array return garbage values

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

```
class Solution{
    public:
    
    //Function to rotate an array by d elements in counter-clockwise direction. 
    void rotateArr(int arr[], int d, int n){
        int i,j=0,l=0;
        
        for(l=0;l<=d-1;l++){
            int temp=arr[0];
            for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
               
               
                
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                
            }
            
            arr[i]=temp;
            
        }
      
        // code here
    }
};
```

For Input:
size:5  rotate :2
1 2 3 4 5
expected output
3,4,5,1,2
your output is:
3 4 5 32766 4196870

the last 2 values is returning as garbage values i dont know why

Comment: If `n` is the size of the array (number of elements) then the loop condition `i <= n` will go out of bounds of the array. Not to mention that using `i + 1` as index will go out of bounds before even that. And after the inner loop, `i` will be *two* steps out of bounds (with the current loop condition).

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: FYI -- Your solution is poor if `n` is a very large number.  Consider using `%` (modulus).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have an off-by-more-than-one error.

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
arr[i] = temp;
```

Let's look at what this does.

n is 5. So your array has 5 items in it. On your first pass, you do:

```
arr[0] = 2;
arr[1] = 3;
arr[2] = 4;
arr[3] = 5;
arr[4] = garbage;
arr[5] = more garbage;
```

At this point, i actually is six, so you:

```
arr[6] = 1;
```

I think if you change your for-loop to this, it will work better:

```
for (i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++)
```

When you end, i will be equal to 4 (the index of the last item in the array), and thus you'll put 0 where you want it.